# current utilities to remove "old" kernels and related files for 20.04

Tags: kernel

I have read
[RemoveOldKernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels)

Various older Ubuntu utilities have been deprecated (obsolete).  Is there any simpler, SAFE, GUI method or is the information in RemoveOldKernels all there is?  An individually developed script that works for a reader of this question is a possibility, but I would prefer an "official" Ubuntu solution that has more generally been tested and debugged.

Comment: The "official" Ubuntu solution is to let the automatic script do it's job. If that's not working, then something is wrong.

Comment: I'm using `purge-old-kernels` script from [`byobu` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=purge-old-kernels) for years without issues.

Comment: ```Software Updater``` (SU) did work this time -- the first time SU popped-up, it offered a new kernel.  Upon reboot, SU again popped-up and offered to remove the previous kernel and components; but this has not always worked, and I have left-over kernels and related files.

Comment: I just installed ```sudo apt-get install byobu```  .SYNOPSIS
       purge-old-kernels

DESCRIPTION
       This utility is now deprecated.  The functionality it used  to  provide
       should be integrated into apt(8).

  If  you  still  have old kernels lying around after this, please file a
       bug against apt: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+filebug   End man page for the above.  Thus, something else is needed.  Is there a way to get ```apt``` to do what the above used to do?

Comment: You can use synaptic.